# Issue installing a SQL Security Update on Windows Server 2012 R2

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, windows-update, sql-server-2012

We're having a weird issue with the "Security Update for SQL Server 2012 Service Pack 4 CU (KB4583465)" update on one of our servers. It will show as installing successfully, but then after a reboot it shows as pending again. It shows every time it has been installed in the update history as well.

We have also tried uninstalling the update and installing it manually from the update catalog, but we have ended up with the same results.

Any ideas would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The system requirements for this update reads:

*Supported Operating System
Windows Server 2008 R2, Windows Server 2008, Windows 8, Windows 8.1, Windows Server 2003, Windows 7, Windows Vista, Windows XP
This update is applicable to SQL Server 2012 SP4 instances installed on supported Windows operating systems.*

Which seems strange to me but it looks like the update isn't supported on Windows Server 2012 R2.

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=102625